# Search elements over all frames

Tags: qt, qt5, qwebview

I need to get elements that show up on pop up on QWebView but the regular way I retrieve elements isn't working for this one.

The HTML look like this (I got this from Web Inspector):

```
<tr class="normal">
    <td>
        <a href="javascript:doSOmething(123, lnkCode)">123</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

where I try to extract like this:

```
 QWebElement doc = webControl.page()->mainFrame()->documentElement();
 QWebElementCollection ahrefs = doc.findAll("tr[class='normal'] a[href*=lnkCode]");
```

Where webControl is of [`QWebView`](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qwebview.html) type. This HTML, as I mentioned, is inside a pop up so I tried too:

```
QWebElementCollection ahrefs = webControl.page()->mainFrame()->findAllElements("tr[class='normal'] a[href*=lnkCode]");
```

But neither returned result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try recursively searching all the [child frames](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qwebframe.html#childFrames). Presumably, the popup has its own document, and therefore has its own frame.